# Greenplum issue : function cannot execute on segment because it accesses relation

Tags: stored-functions, greenplum

I am using a Greenplum database. Below is the function definition which I used to execute.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfunc(IN id int, OUT rate double precision)
RETURNS double precision AS
$BODY$
begin
select count(*) into rate from ref_test_V
return;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

And when I call this function in the select list it throwing me below error

**Query:** select 1,testfunc(id) from ref_test

**ERROR:** XX000: function cannot execute on segment because it accesses relation "public.ref_test_v" (functions.c:155)  (seg25 slice1 *****.com 1026 pid=193132) (cdbdisp.c:1326)

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in Greenplum.  Think about what it is would be doing too if it were supported.  It would get one row from a segment, then do a count(*) from itself.  The next row would be retrieved and it again would do a count(*).

A pure SQL way to do this is:

```
with x as (select count(*) as total_count from ref_test_V)
select 1, x.total_count from ref_test, x;
```

If you don't like using a Common Table Expression, you can do it with a subquery.

```
select 1, x.total_count 
from   ref_test, 
       (select count(*) as total_count 
       from ref_test_V) as x;
```

Comment: I Understand that, But what I'm trying to ask is I want to fetch the count of some table with a filter value based on the argument from the function and the function is called from other table in select list. If my syntax is wrong could you point me at the right syntax. A sample code will help me. Please note that I dont want to implement as SQL. TIA  :)

Comment: You'll have to execute two different SQL statements (one with the count and the next with other select) or use a variable in the function to capture the count of records.

Comment: I have tried as you told, but the issue still persists. Could you provide any sample code which could help me. I tried everything to read the record count of a table from function and when I call this function from a select list of another table keep on receiving the same issue. TIA

Comment: :) I want to admin that my function is more critical than what I have explained in this blog & the issue is caused because of which I told earlier, that is why I made it simple. I cant implement that function as a SQL or as CTE due to its complexity. Hope if you could help me find a solution for this problem.

Comment: I think you are trying to use functions in a way that it wasn't intended for in Greenplum.  You should limit using functions in inline SQL unless you are just encapsulating common transformations of data.  You are trying to use it to query a table which you shouldn't do.

Comment: Is it not possible to read a tables data from a function when called from a select list. The above function is working when called separately with constant values as argument but not working when called in the select list. Hope is there any other  way to overcome this or inline SQL is the only way

Comment: It is possible but it can't be the same table.  But, the function is executed for each row returned so this is a very inefficient way to do this.  A subquery or CTE would be a better choice.

Comment: Yes that I agree and I also tried with two different tables still the issue remains. Yes a subquery or CTE would be more efficient, but the complexity of the function made me to go with function conversion. So it would be helpful if you could show me the right syntax for the above mentioned function so that I could implement this in my function.

Comment: It isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function from the table like below.

```
select 1, (select testfunc(5)) from ref_test;
```

Comment: Its working if you pass constant value as a parameter, its not working when your passing column from ref_test , that is what I'm implying.